# mongoose $regex on object or nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search

```
const AdressSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    location: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
})
```

location is where I want to find any matching expression

this is how I do it but returns empty result

```
async get() {
   return this.Model.find($or: [{ title: { $regex: regex } },{location: { $regex: regex } }])
  }
```

Comment: Add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions match strings.

MongoDB query language operators are type sensitive.

`type: Object` is not a string.

Therefore the `$regex` operator will never match a `location`.